# Registering a Amazon SQS for MWS notifications

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-mws

I  wanna start with Supcriptions API but when I try to register my SQS I get

```
    <ErrorResponse xmlns="http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/Subscriptions/2013-07-01">
    <Error>
        <Type>Sender</Type>
        <Code>MalformedInput</Code>
        <Message>Start of list found where not expected</Message>
    </Error>
    <RequestId>709c516e-2e2e-403c-b9d1-fb209ba5049b</RequestId>
    </ErrorResponse>
```

This is my Request

```
    POST
    mws-eu.amazonservices.com
    /Subscriptions/2013-07-01
    AWSAccessKeyId=<deleted>&
    Action=RegisterDestination&
    Destination.AttributeList.member.1.Key=sqsQueueUrl&
    Destination.AttributeList.member.1.Value=https%3A%2F%2Fsqs.us-east-2.amazonaws.com%<deleted>%2Fpricechanges&
    Destination.DeliveryChannel=SQS&
    MarketplaceId.Id.1=A1PA6795UKMFR9&
    SellerId=<deleted>&
    SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256&
    SignatureVersion=2&
    Timestamp=2019-07-15T07%3A50%3A06.000Z&
    Version=2013-07-01
```

What's wrong here?

Comment: I always just used the scratchpad for these.  Fill in all your info and submit it.  Unless you have a need to start/stop multiple times and it would be easier to program it.  In regards to your issue, I don't know by looking at it.

Comment: Well you'r right there is no need to register per script. I registered my destination now via scratchpad and created the subscription. Don't know what is wrong with my code anyway. But thank you now I can work.

Comment: great!   Lots of people here ask what's wrong with their request and what I've found is to just use scratchpad using sample data.  Look at the request that it generates, then plug in your "real" data.